# Udev rule doesn't allow Ubuntu to wake on USB Resume sequencing, but NixOS does

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, sleep

I've got a Lenovo ThinkPad T480 running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon running NixOS, and a USB Device with vendor ID 0x36dc. The USB Device is capable of remote wakeup USB Resume Signalling, per USB Specification Revision 2.0, section 7.1.7.7, and confirmed by a TotalPhase USB signal analyzer.

I have the following udev rule on both laptops: `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="36dc", MODE:="0660", TAG+="uaccess", ATTR{power/wakeup}="enabled"`.

The Ubuntu laptop does not wake from sleep when receiving the remote wakeup signal. The NixOS laptop does.

The Ubuntu laptop has `enabled` in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/<PORT>/power/wakeup` for any port I plug the Device into, so the udev rule is clearly working. `/proc/acpi/wakeup` shows `enabled` for the `XHC` device which has the same PCI path as the USB controller the Device is plugged into.

What else could be preventing the Ubuntu laptop from waking up?